# Problems with regex in PowerShell

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

First, I am completly new to regex and trying really hard to understand but getting very frustrated with it. Please bare with me here.

I am having problem understanding regex in PowerShell. I have tested a regex on both https://regexr.com/ and on https://regex101.com/r/zT5dL7/3. I then transfer the regex to powershell but the result is not what I am getting in powershell.

I need to get hold of the actual build number which looks like '(any number)-(any number)', where any number which over time will be bigger and bigger.

I get the string from a json from our jenkins api, convert it form json and get the string that holds the buildnumber.

```
$r = & $c @a | ConvertFrom-Json

$t= $r.fullDisplayName | Out-String

$t -replace '[^#0-9)][0-9-]+[0-9]'
```

Ran regex `[^#0-9)][0-9-]+[0-9]` on input string `#1737 - 1725-74033 - x64,x86` and I expect to get a reduced string like `1725-74033x64,x86` but instead I get `#1737 - - ,` and I do not understand why.

Feel free to expand my regex if I can get rid of both `x86` and `x64`and the leading whitespace in the beginning. So the final result would be `1725-74033`.

Comment: [`$t -replace '.*?([0-9]+-[0-9]+).*','$1'`](https://regex101.com/r/NBGMI8/1)

Comment: `'#1737 - 1725-74033 - x64,x86' -replace '^#\d+\D+(\d+-\d+).*', '$1'` --> `1725-74033`

Comment: Why has the question been tagged with C#? Surely you know that Powershell and C# are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i didnt understand what -replace actually did as it **removes** the actual matches and is left with everything else. Above works just need to use -match instead of -replace and the result is in $Matches.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is replacing the characters which you are trying to capture.

I have assumed that the pattern you've put here is predictable. E.g. the length of the numbers and order of characters won't change.

### The code

```
[string] $s = '#1737 - 1725-74033 - x64,x86'

$buildNumber = [regex]::Match($s, '#[0-9]{4}\s-\s([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5})\s-\sx64,x86').Groups[1].Value

Write-Output $buildNumber
```

### The output

```
PS C:\Users\ben> [string] $s = '#1737 - 1725-74033 - x64,x86'

$buildNumber = [regex]::Match($s, '#[0-9]{4}\s-\s([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5})\s-\sx64,x86').Groups[1].Value

Write-Output $buildNumber
1725-74033

PS C:\Users\ben>
```

What this does is;

- match the pattern of your build output
- creates a group for the build number using `(capture in parens)`
- gets the capture using regex **Match()** instead of regex replace.

Regex101 does a terrific job of explaining the individual bits of regex.
https://regex101.com/r/xzak5z/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `-replace` to remove unwanted characters: (this follows your example data)

```
PS > $s = '#1737 - 1725-74033 - x64,x86'
PS > $s -replace '(^#\d+ - )|\s'
1725-74033-x64,x86
```

If you want to match desired characters: (this is 'AnyNumber-AnyNumber' per your descriptive text)

```
PS > $s -match '\d+-\d+'
True
PS > $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              1725-74033
```